# Do I need 3 try blocks for url encode?

Tags: java, try-catch, processing, urlencode

I tried this:

```
String query = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address="+country+"+"+province+"+"+city+"&sensor=false";

try {
    query = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    println("getLatLonFromAdress URLEncoder error: "+e);
    return  new float[] { -1f, -1f };
}
```

but it turns the url into:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fmaps.googleapis.com%2Fmaps%2Fapi%2Fgeocode%2Fxml%3Faddress%3DCanada%2BAlberta%2BGrande+Cache%26sensor%3Dfalse
```

So I only want to encode country, province and city. Is it bad to handle that in one try block? Like:

```
try {
    country = URLEncoder.encode(country, "UTF-8");
    province = URLEncoder.encode(province, "UTF-8");
    city = URLEncoder.encode(city, "UTF-8");
}
catch (Exception e) {…}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UnsupportedEncodingException will not be thrown if you are passing "UTF-8" as that will always be present. Therefor you can happily handle them all in 1 catch.

Comment: Another problem with checked exceptions.  You know an error won't happen, but compiler forces you to write useless crap anyway.